# Removing internal padding from td elements

Tags: html, css, alignment, padding

Is it possible to remove the internal `padding` from `td` elements? For I have in a table row two `td` elements, the second is 2 lines of text while the first is one line only. This is causing unwanted vertical `padding` in the first `td` element, which I seem not be able to remove.

Comment: Other things being equal, the cells have exactly the same padding. What you regard as padding is apparently something else. You should explain the problem in terms of visible rendering, not assumed CSS properties. You probably want to tune vertical alignment, but you don’t specify how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just align text to the top with :

```
td { vertical-align: top; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7owwt9gj/1/)

Comment: This may address the OP’s real problem, but it does not address the question actually asked—about padding.

Comment: This solves the problem of aligning the text to the top but not the removing of padding, which is just shifted to the bottom.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela : Well, as `td` content is`middle`- aligned by default, which causes `padding` to appear both in cells and as OP's problem, then I suggested the most reasonable solution - change vertical alignment.

Comment: @notulysses, no, `vertical-align` does not affect `padding` at all, as you can see by inspecting the cells using a browsers dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be:
`td { display: inline-block; }`